# Sfml lostFocus / gainedFocus cpu usage

Tags: c++, sfml, cpu-usage

Why when I run this simple code and just doing nothing CPU usage by this app is around 0.4%

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "hi", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    sf::Event event;

    bool lostFocus = false;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::LostFocus)
                lostFocus = true;
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::GainedFocus)
                lostFocus = false;
        }
        if (!lostFocus)
        {
            window.clear(sf::Color::White);
            window.display();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I click on other app, CPU usage by this app increases to 12%.
Does `GainedFocus` actually eat so much cpu power or what?
(I just wanted to make a simple pause of game and saw this cpu usage)

Comment: You are polling for events rather than waiting for events. That's, more or less, a busy loop.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, What do you mean ?Do I have some way to wait for events? ^-^' Or you mean just set frame rate lower?

Comment: SFML has a `waitEvent()` API as a companion to `pollEvent()`. It's all in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, when your window doesn't have focus and you're not updating the window, the loop goes into a hot spin where it's continuously checking for events. When you've lost focus, you instead want to block and wait for a `GainedFocus` event to occur. As a very simple example, you could do something like

```
void block_until_gained_focus(sf::Window& window) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (true) {
        if (window.waitEvent(event) && event.type == sf::Event::GainedFocus) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your main game loop could look something like

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        else if (event.type == sf::Event::LostFocus)
            wait_until_gained_focus(window);
    }
    window.clear(sf::Color::White);
    window.display();
}
```

Now if you wanted to do additional work while focus is lost you'll need a different implementation, but the key here is to use [`waitEvent`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#aaf02ab64fbc1d374eef3696df54137bc) instead of `pollEvent`.